# Android + Eclipse How to import Enhanced ListView project into mine?

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, import, project

I'm a little newbie on Android programming and the Eclipse IDE.
And I'm having some difficulties to import this lib/project (how do I call it?) into my currently project.

The link to the GitHub repo:
https://github.com/timroes/EnhancedListView/wiki

There the author wrote a "How to include", but I tried the last one (by my one), since I use Eclipse.

> "How to include
>
> You need to include the library into your project, by one of the
>   following ways:
>
> ```
> Include it from Maven Central (recommended)
>
> Just enter the following line to your build.gradle file in the dependencies section:
>
> compile 'de.timroes.android:EnhancedListView:X.Z.Y@aar'
>
> Where X.Y.Z is a valid release. You can find all releases on the release page or directly in Maven Central.
>
> If you use Maven to build, just use the above coordinates in your pom.xml.
>
> Download the aar file from the release page and reference it in the dependencies section of your build.gradle:
>
> compile files('libs/EnhancedListView-X.Y.Z.aar')
>
> If you are using Eclipse or Ant, you are on your own. You most likely want to download the sources and import them in your build system."
> ```

I tried to include it to the build path, but didn't work. Nothing found on internet. Do I have to include something besides adding project into build path? Do I import it like a lib or project?

Do any of the others options to include would work for me? How do I do it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: put classpath 'de.timroes.android:EnhancedListView:0.3.+@aar' in your "outer" gradle file in dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no one click method for Eclipse users. You have to copy the EnhancedListView.java into one of your src packages, the content of the resource directories into your project's resource directories and the annotations.jar from the libs directory to your libs directory.